# Java to C# format specifiers

Tags: java, c#, formatting

I am new to C# having used Java.

I am looking to output an expression of 4.5 - 2.7...  In Java I would simply write System.out.format("%.2f\n", 4.5 - 2.7);

In C#, I have used Console.WriteLine(4.5 - 2.7); but I am looking to print 2 decimal places.
Could someone be so kind as to explain how I achieve this?

Comment: if my answer solves your question, could you pelase mark as 'answered'?

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Format` [(Link To Documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0)
Use the format `{Parameter Number:Decimal Places}`

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" We are going to format 15.6345 as {0:0.00}",15.6345));
```

Test it [here!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/).
Good luck!

**EDIT / Clarification**

By `Parameter Number`, String.Format takes all other inputs after the first input of a string to be values to format and place into the string.
Every time {x:yyz} appears in the string, System.String.Format will format `x` in the style `yyz`, where `x` is the index of the value passed in.
In my example above, `15.6345` is `x`, and the format `0.00` is `yyz`.

You could format 2 numbers or repeat one by going:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" We are going to format 15.6345 as {0:0.00} , the format 3.123 as 3.1 {1:0.0} , then repeat 15.6345 as 15.6 {0:0.0}",15.6345,3.123));
```

Comment: Awesome! I used Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", 4.5 - 2.7));   and it worked as expected. Thank you so much!